# Laravel header blade language switcher for multi-language site

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a `header.blade` with language links. When the user clicks the link, I want the page to refresh in the correct language, but when the user clicks on the link page is refresh and still is on the same language.

**header.blade.php**

```
@foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $locale)
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
            href="{{ route(\Route::currentRouteName(), \Route::current()->parameters(), $locale) }}"
            @if (app()->getLocale() == $locale) style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" @endif>{{ strtoupper($locale) }}</a>
    </li> 
@endforeach
```

Routing works fine on all site, only the language switcher won't work.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@login');
    Route::get('faq', 'PagesController@faq')->name('faq');
    Route::get('dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

**Middleware setLocale**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
    return $next($request);
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: what does your setlocale middleware contain?

Comment: @Dave I added in the post